# How to integrate antd-mobile text input as controlled component with downshift?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd-mobile, downshift

I would like to **use the autocomplete from [downshift](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift) in my antd-mobile web-app**. I like downshift as it renders external components.

Unfortunately **I could not figure out, how to 'bind' one of the [one](https://mobile.ant.design/components/input-item/) / [two](https://mobile.ant.design/components/textarea-item/) text input elements from antd-mobile**. The components offer a 'controlled' mode, but I couldn't find the respective docs.

Just passing on the `getInputProps()` from downshift doesn't work:

```js
<InputItem {...downshift.getInputProps()} />
```

downshift throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

This happens when downshift reads `event.target.value` on the only callback argument provided (`event`) by the antd-mobile component (calling-back `onChange()`). This makes sense as the antd-mobile api-doc says that a 'string' type value of the text input is returned.

**So, how do I get the original react `<input>` component `onChange` callback from the antd-mobile component to pass it on?**

Looking into the source: I lost track [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/blob/723a2084e691866f32af100d9cd7cde0f359a51b/components/input-item/Input.tsx#L45). The `onChange` callback should be set to `this.props.onChange` (included in `restProps`). Which in turn should be set by `getInputProps()` from downshift: Object.keys of return value are:

```
["aria-autocomplete", "aria-activedescendant", "aria-controls", "aria-labelledby", "autoComplete", "value", "id", "onChange", "onKeyDown", "onBlur"]
```

**And looking into the future**: Given the `onChange` callback gets through to downshift - will there be more binding necessary?